# Python: Importing a class from a file only given the class name and a path

Tags: python, import, python-import, python-importlib

I am trying to make a system to load drivers from a given path in a json file.

How can I do this?

I have tried:

```
import sys
import importlib
import json

jsonfile = open("test.json")
json_contents = json.load(jsonfile)

sys.path.append(json_contents["Path to drivers"])

Driver_Module = importlib.import_module(json_contents["Class File Name"])

print(sys.modules)

from Driver_Module import DriverModuleClass
```

But I get the error that no module named 'Driver_Module' exists. The problem is that the name of the "Class File Name" is imported in the print as whatever that is.

Without the "From" I get "No Module Named DriverModuleClass" even though that is the name of the class inside the module which is added to the sys.modules already.

Comment: `Driver_Module` is a variable name, not a module name. The name of the module is the name of whatever file `json_contents["Class File Name"])` contains.

Comment: You don't need to import it again, the module is already in `Driver_Module` so you can just do `DriverModuleClass = Driver_Module.DriverModuleClass`